# Deserializing an element with different xsi:style

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-deserialization

I need to deserialize a XML file that contains an element with two different types.
Example:

```
<loop xsi:type="loopDynamicLengthType">
...
<loop xsi:type="loopTerminatedType">
...
```

In my source the class is defined as:

```
<XmlElement("loop")> Public prLoop() As PosResponseLoop
```

The second one is defined as:

```
<XmlInclude(GetType(loopTerminatedType))> _
Public Class PosResponseLoop
```

The first one could be defined in a similar way and the same name,

```
<XmlInclude(GetType(loopDynamicLengthType))> _
Public Class PosResponseLoop
```

but the compiler says:

```
class 'PosResponseLoop' and class 'PosResponseLoop' conflict in namespace 'WindowsApplication1'.
```

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard attribute [`xsi:type`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type) allows an XML element to explicitly assert its type.  In this case, the element `<loop>` can have two types, `loopDynamicLengthType` and `loopTerminatedType`.  As explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca1ks327.aspx), `XmlSerializer` uses the `xsi:type` information to map the XML element to a specific .Net type.  Thus what you need to do is have a single base class (possibly though not necessarily abstract) to represent any possible type of loop, with two subclasses, each corresponding to the two possible `xsi:type` values:

```
<XmlInclude(GetType(LoopTerminatedType))> _
<XmlInclude(GetType(LoopDynamicLengthType))> _
Public MustInherit Class PosResponseLoop
End Class

<XmlType("loopTerminatedType")> _
Public Class LoopTerminatedType
    Inherits PosResponseLoop
End Class

<XmlType("loopDynamicLengthType")> _
Public Class LoopDynamicLengthType
    Inherits PosResponseLoop
End Class
```

The [`<XmlInclude>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx) attributes on the base class specify the set of possible subtypes that might be encountered.  The [`<XmlType(String)>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.aspx) attributes on the derived classes specify the name that will appear as the value of the corresponding `xsi:type` attribute.

Then your containing type should look like:

```
Public Class RootObject
    <XmlElement("loop")> Public prLoop() As PosResponseLoop 
End Class
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MTqJiy).